# How to get floats value without including exponential notation

Tags: c#, floating-point, tostring

In C#, is it possible to perform ToString on a float and get the value without using exponentials?

For example, consider the following:

```
float dummy;

dummy = 0.000006F;

Console.WriteLine(dummy.ToString());
```

This gives the output

```
6E-06
```

However, what I was is

```
0.000006
```

The closest I could find was using the "F" qualifier, however I then need to specify the number of decimal places otherwise the value get rounded.

Is there actually a way of doing this automatically or do I need to do a load of funky logic to either trim zeroes or figure out the number of required decimals.

Thanks;
Richard Moss

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try this

```
Console.WriteLine(dummy.ToString("F"));
```

You can also specify number of decimal places. For example F5, F3, etc.

Also, you can check custom format specifier

```
Console.WriteLine(dummy.ToString("0.#########"));
```

Comment: Yes, as mentioned I already tried this. However, I need to specify the number of decimal places which I won't necessarily  know (unless there's something else I'm missing ;)) - I'm somewhat surprised that I can't seem to do this except with the E notation which my users don't want.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I had to read more carefully. So, if you want to display the float number you should declare maximal decimal precision to show. By the way, float type doesn't provide high level of precision (~10^(-39)) and you can just choose the big enough amount of decimal places

Comment: I had also tried this, ie F10, but the "side effect" was that the zeroes continued after the 6. I had hoped to avoid this, but if it is going to be the only way I can strip of the extra zero's I suppose. It just seems so ... clunky!

Comment: Maybe the custom format will help you. Try this: Console.WriteLine(dummy.ToString("0.#########")); it will print maximum 9 decimal places and cut trailing zeros

Comment: BTW, .Net decimal type is preferable for decimal calculations

Comment: @Richard have you considered using the decimal type instead? It sounds like this may be a better fit for what you want.

Comment: While as you say it might make a lot of sense to use the decimal type unfortunately that would be a major change and not something I can do in the short term.

Answer (score 3):

```
string dum = string.Format("{0:f99}",dummy).TrimEnd('0');
if (dum.EndsWith(",")) dum = dum.Remove(dum.Length - 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Without some further background info, it's hard to tell - but it sounds like you want decimal semantics. So why not use the `decimal` type instead?

```
decimal dummy;
dummy = 0.000006M;
```

The decimal type is more accurate at representing decimal numbers than `float` or `double`, but it is not as performant. See [here](http://gregs-blog.com/2007/12/10/dot-net-decimal-type-vs-float-type/) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

```
Console.WriteLine(dummy.ToString("N5"));
```

where 5 its number of decimal places

Comment: Thanks for the response, this is also something I've already tried and suffers the same issue as the F qualifier in that I need to explicitly specify a precision which I won't know.

Answer (score 0):

```
float dummy = 0.000006F;
Console.WriteLine(dummy.ToString("0." + new string('#', 60)));
```

If you'll be doing this a lot then it makes sense to store the format string in a `static` field/property somewhere and re-use it, rather than constructing a new `string` every time:

```
private static readonly string _allFloatDigits = "0." + new string('#', 60);

// ...

float dummy = 0.000006F;
Console.WriteLine(dummy.ToString(_allFloatDigits));
```